# ckeditor "You don't have permission to access"

Tags: ckeditor

i use ckeditor on my web and i have a little problame...

when i submit the form without img or iframe it's work fine and submitting the form but...
if i put iframe or img in the field it's open error.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /admin/acc/prices.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to andle the request.

here my code:
http://pastebin.com/UzUGRkRq

i have this problame just on this page... on other pages with ckeditor everything works fine.

***edit***
now i see that the problam happens everytime that i use somthing from the editor and not regular char

help me please.
thanks.

Comment: Please include some code as well. How do you handle the submit, how do you submit for example. Also a link would be nice if you have it.